# Cycle through class files with identical functions

Tags: java

I was wondering for a way to cycle through multiple different class files with identical functions and paramaters. I have a way of doing it below, but I was hoping for a better way of going about it.

```
String item = "item";
ImageIcon ii = null;
            try {
                ii = BattleItemGallery.getIcon(item, false);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                try {
                    ii = BerryGallery.getIcon(item, false);
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    try {
                        ii = EventItemGallery.getIcon(item, false);
                    } catch (Exception e3) {
                        try {
                            ii = EvolutionGallery.getIcon(item, false);
                        } catch (Exception e4) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Basically the code is to try and look for an ImageIcon in the class file and if it throws an error, aka can't find it, then it will try the next file, so on so forth. I was thinking of maybe finding a way to put the class files in an ArrayList somehow without having to initialize an object for each.

If anyone has any better ideas that would be awesome.

Comment: Possible [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). `getIcon` should probably not be static, but it's hard to say without more context.

Comment: Can you change `getIcon` to return an `Optional<ImageIcon>` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Have the functional references in a list and try with that.
for example:

```
List<BiFunction<String, Boolean, ImageIcon>> functions = List.of(EvolutionGallery::getIcon, BerryGallery::getIcon, EventItemGallery::getIcon, BattleItemGallery::getIcon);
ImageIcon imageIcon = null;
for(BiFunction<String, Boolean, ImageIcon> function: functions) {
    try{
        imageIcon = function.apply(item, false);
    } catch(RuntimeException ignored){}
}
if(Objects.isNull(imageIcon)) {
    // handle condition
}
```

I can't comment on the logic inside the functions without the knowledge of the system, but if there are multiple cases where an exception is thrown in case of resource not being present, i.e., absent `imageIcon` try replacing the return value with an `Optional<ImageIcon>` or simply return `null`.
This is generally a better practice compared to throwing an exception and would help you debug in case any issue arises in the future.

if you want to throw an exception, throw it in the **if block** written in the above example so that the source of the exception can be pinpointed better.

---

[BiFunction documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html)